# Big-O notation for a recursive algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm, recursion, big-o

I'm having trouble with a recursion problem of uni.

I have to get the big-O order of a recursive algorithm, this is the recursion scheme I got:

[image: Recursion scheme]

It comes from an algorithm that uses an `V[a..b]` array and makes this return when `b-a+1` is `> 3`:

```
return V(X) + f(V, a, Y) + f(V, Z, b)
```

Where `Y` is `(2a+b)/3` and `Z` is `(a+2b)/3`.

How could I solve it?

Comment: Have a look at the [master theorem's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem). If none of these are applicable, you might need to unfold the recursion call stack and analyze the unfolded pattern.

Comment: I'm probably wrong, but it looks like `log_3(n)`